# How to parse xml file with python when one tag has two types?

Tags: python, xml

I want to parse a xml file using python package `xml.etree.cElementTree`.In my xml file, tag `<edge>` has two types of atrrs. Say

```
<edge id=":4_0" function="internal">
    <lane id=":4_0_0" index="0" speed="16.70" length="4.82" shape="0.20,756.75 -1.13,756.08 -1.64,755.31 -1.33,754.44 -0.20,753.48"/>
</edge>

<edge id="-13" from="12" to="1" priority="-1">
    <lane id="-13_0" index="0" speed="16.70" length="1580.67" shape="2665.90,1464.08 1332.42,615.33"/>
    <lane id="-13_1" index="1" speed="16.70" length="1580.67" shape="2667.67,1461.29 1334.19,612.54"/>
    <lane id="-13_2" index="2" speed="16.70" length="1580.67" shape="2669.44,1458.51 1335.97,609.76"/>
    <lane id="-13_3" index="3" speed="16.70" length="1580.67" shape="2671.21,1455.72 1337.74,606.97"/>
</edge>
```

The parse result of tag `edge` finds only **one**

```
<edge id=":4_0" function="internal">
```

> When I delete all
>
> ```
> `<edge id=":4_0" function="internal">`
> ```
>
> it can parse successfully:
>
> ```
> `<edge id="-13" from="12" to="1" priority="-1">`
> ```

So how can I fix it?

I want to parse `<edge id="-13" from="12" to="1" priority="-1">` when both type of tag `edge` exist.Thx.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the code that you have already tried?

Comment: Works for me, Output: `<Element data at 0xf704e52c>`, 
`:4_0`, 
`-13`